# Facebook Jobs API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have a rudimentary understanding of how the Facebook API works; I can use the Graph API to post messages but that's it so far.  However, we also want to post Jobs.  Facebook appears to have a custom UI specifically for posting jobs and for receiving applications, but I can't seem to find anything in the API documentation about posting a job.  All my searches yield tons of advertisements for Facebook developer jobs, but nothing on how to actually use the Facebook API to post jobs.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like there used to be something here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-api/getting-started

Nothing there anymore...

Answer (score 6):

From Facebook on 6 Sep 2018

Hi Nicholas,

Thanks for getting in touch. Jobs API is currently in closed beta. We do not support closed beta products through this channel. I would suggest reaching out to your business partner regarding this.

Please refer to this page on how to apply to become Facebook marketing partner: https://www.facebook.com/business/marketing-partners/about/facebook-marketing-partner-requirements

Sergey

Comment: Why would this response get down voted?  It's not the answer I want, but it explains why I can't find anything useful

Answer (score 1):

This was released in the UK today as far as I can see. I've trawled everywhere and every link I can find that relates to 'facebook jobs api' has been removed. That tells me they have no current API, which kind of makes sense as its a new service so is likely to change a lot before they can begin to think about API access.

Comment: They have an api it is just a closed api only available to select partners. LinkedIn also has similar partner level only api's not publicly available.